# Repeated form data to Django form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

Consider a basic Django form:

```
from django import forms
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When you pass this form `request.POST`, as in `TestForm(request.POST)`, it receives the `QueryDict` instance from the requests's `form`(s):

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict
qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd["first_name"] = "Brad"
qd["last_name"] = "Solomon"
TestForm(qd).is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
# True
```

But now what I'd like to do is handle multiple row-like repetitions of these same two fields:

```
<form method="POST" action="/some/endpoint">
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="first_name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

I.e.

[image]

**What's the proper way to iterate over each of these cleaned and validated (`first_name`, `last_name`) pairs?**

If I pass the whole thing to a `TestForm`, then `.cleaned_data` only takes the last-seen pair:

```
>>> qd = QueryDict(mutable=True) 
... qd.setlist("first_name", ["Brad", "Joe"]) 
... qd.setlist("last_name", ["Solomon", "Smith"])                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> form = TestForm(qd)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>>> form.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
True
>>> form.cleaned_data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
{'first_name': 'Joe', 'last_name': 'Smith'}
```

(For what it's worth, it does make sense that only the last value is shown because this mimics `QueryDict` behavior.  However, I'd like to access all values rather than just the last-seen.)

Comment: You should use a formset.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've seen [Understanding the ManagementForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) - the issue here is that I don't have control over the `<form>` itself; it's being submitted to its `action` value and I receive it just like it is above with no prefixes.

Comment: So what's the point of using a form at all? What will you do if the data does not validate? What response are you returning?

Comment: One big reason for using the form is for field validation @DanielRoseman.  But, I understand what you're getting at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use a formset, you'll just have to do things manually.

The rough idea here is

```py
def view(request):
  # (add the usual `if method == POST` stuff here)
  first_names = request.POST.getlist('first_name')
  last_names = request.POST.getlist('last_name')
  thingamabobs = request.POST.getlist('thingamabob')
  for first_name, last_name, thingamabob in zip(first_names, last_names, thingamabobs):
    f = NameForm(data={
      'first_name': first_name,
      'last_name': last_name,
      'thingamabob': thingamabob,
    })
    if not f.is_valid:
      # ... do something here
    f.save()  # or something
```

Getting the data back to the view to re-populate the fields post-POST should things not validate will also be a little annoying here.